# No nscd daemon on my CentOS box, where/how does DNS caching happen then?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I do not seem to have a nscd service on my Cent 6.3 server.  I am not running BIND on it, but I am curious about the DNS client caching.  How does this happen on a standard minimal install of Cent 6.3 when the NSCD daemon is not present?

Comment: What makes you think your box is doing any cacheing at all?

Comment: It's very possible that it isn't.  I guess that is what I am trying to determine.  Is there any mechanism for DNS client caching outside of NSCD?

Comment: Well, almost all versions of BIND cache, unless you work hard to tell them not to.  So if you were running BIND locally, that might well cache; if you weren't, your upstream nameserver (see `/etc/resolv.conf`) almost certainly will.

Comment: I am only concerned with DNS client in this case.

Answer (score 4):

**Server:**

You can test if a DNS resolver is caching DNS results by looking at the timing output of "dig".

```
dig ohdns.org | grep sec
  ;; Query time: 146 msec
```

If you make the same query twice and see a small number, close to 0msec, then your nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf is caching results.  I would expect the name server you have listed in /etc/resolv.conf to cache results that you query.

**Client:**

DNS caching does not happen by default in CentOS.  You would have to enable nscd, bind, unbound, dnsmasque or some other DNS caching mechanism.

You did not mention the background of this request.  If this is application specific, that can also be a factor.  For example, Firefox will cache DNS results as well.  Some server applications can also cache DNS results, such as Java.  Java and DNS cache are a fun and complex topic.