# When domain does not exist TLD is changed into a SLD

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, linux-networking

Today i've noticed something strange. When I lookup a domain that does not exist my linux server will change the TLD (Top-Level-Domain) into a SLD (Second-Level-Domain) and append a regional TLD to it. (in this case .nl). My server is located in a dutch datacenter and has a dutch regional IP so that might be a clue?

domain: nujklfdjaklfjkal.**com** becomes nujklfdjaklfjkal.**com.nl**

domain: jkfdjaklfjkalfjdkafjdkla.**net** becomes jkfdjaklfjkalfjdkafjdkla.**net.nl**

```
[root@example ~]# ping nujklfdjaklfjkal.com
PING nujklfdjaklfjkal.com.nl (83.98.157.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.com.nl (83.98.157.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=0.890 ms
64 bytes from www.com.nl (83.98.157.102): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=0.741 ms
64 bytes from www.com.nl (83.98.157.102): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=0.873 ms
^C
--- nujklfdjaklfjkal.com.nl ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2368ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.741/0.834/0.890/0.074 ms

[root@example ~]# ping jkfdjaklfjkalfjdkafjdkla.net
PING jkfdjaklfjkalfjdkafjdkla.net.nl (83.98.157.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.com.nl (83.98.157.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=0.973 ms
64 bytes from www.com.nl (83.98.157.102): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=0.856 ms
64 bytes from www.com.nl (83.98.157.102): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=0.883 ms
^C
```

My resolv.conf doesnt show anything strange and only has the google DNS server in it.

```
[root@example ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

It will get the IP by DHCP and I checked the offering with tcpdump. All looks good and although it does offer 2 DNS servers i've configured the dhcp client to ignore those.

When analysing the tcpdump it shows clearly that google DNS server replies with unknown. Right after that my server does a new lookup for the com.nl domain. So it seems its something that my server does.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFZQq.png

Anyone have an idea?

## Update

For now, I've solved it by adding search localhost to /etc/resolv.conf
However, the question remains why isn't this done by default when I leave search blank.

## Update - August 24th

In my investigation I've made some progress. The hostname of the system was `SLD.TLD` (`example.nl`) instead of `server.example.nl`. It seems, when my server can't find a domain and doesn't have a search configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`, it will get everything behind the first dot in his own hostname (exampe`.nl`) and append it to the end of the destination hostname (jkfldajfkdajfklda.com`.nl`).

That way `jkfldajfkdajfklda.com` becomes `jkfldajfkdajfklda.com.nl` why my server-hostname is example`.nl`. However, when I change the server-hostname to `server.example.nl`, `jkfldajfkdajfklda.com` suddenly becomes `jkfldajfkdajfklda.com.example.nl`.

The question remains where this logic is configured.

Comment: Are you sure you're using google's DNS as from your update? I've observed something similar with some Italian providers, and it was some type of DNS mangling they did at their NSs. The problem disappeared when I switched to Opendns NSs.

Comment: Yeah i'm sure of it. The tcpdump confirms this. Right after the first unknown response from google my server will do another lookup for the new address.

Comment: my resolver configuration has only one line in it. Which is the google nameserver

Comment: Please name your OS.

Comment: centos 6 (latest version)

Comment: Not a frequent user of CentOS, but I see that it usually does not include DNS caching by default. Can you check if any of the caching mechanisms mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/500176/no-nscd-daemon-on-my-centos-box-where-how-does-dns-caching-happen-then) are running on your system?  Also, is there a setting for [domain suffix](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/configure-centos-6-network-settings/) in the interface?

Comment: Also, would you install bind9, set to only listen to localhost, to allow recursion, and set dns forwarders as you like? Then set 127.0.0.1 as resolver and test again name resolution.

Comment: After your update, have you checked if the search domain is passed by DHCP? This might solve your arcane.

Comment: What is your `search` option set to in /etc/resolv.conf ?  If a name isn't found in /etc/hosts or via dns lookup the `search domain` is added to the back and the lookup process starts over.

Comment: In Windows environments, this is set at the NIC level using a setting that tells the OS to try specific DNS suffixes if it can't resolve the name. This process, in Windows, is to help the system to find local resources and let you use names in the command line without having to type their suffixes. For instance, if I have a system with an FQDN of `longservername.internal.longdomainname.com`, I can add `internal.longdomainname.com` to my DNS Suffixes lists and just `ping longservername` to get a result. [See here](http://imgur.com/a/jiKhp)

Comment: Because I have no idea how to turn it off in Linux or where the configuration resides, I won't add an answer. But, to sate your curiosity, I wanted to add my thoughts as to _why_ your system does this. Most admins wouldn't be surprised by this behavior.

Comment: @ivanivan: as soon as I changed my hostname to server.example.com the automatic lookup stopt working. Nothing in `resolv.conf` other then `nameserver 8.8.8.8`